# Stopping one particular command scheduled by at command except others

Tags: at

I am scheduling, say, 3 commands using `at` command.

```
$ at teatime
 command1
 command2
 command3
 <Ctrl + D>
```

After some time I realised that running `command3` is not really what I wanted, but at same time I don't want remaining commands to stopped from execution.

I tried looking for `at` command or something like it in System Monitor so that I could kill process responsible for running `command3` but couldn't find (maybe I am wrong in this). Also I can stop ATD daemon that runs these commands but that will stop all commands from execution, which is not what I wanted.
Is there any other way to stop just `command3` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to cancel all three and re-schedule the ones you want executed. `atq` will show you the list of queued tasks, `at -c` will show you one queued task by number, and `atrm` will remove one task by number.

Your underlying problem is that everything from invocation of `at` to the ctrl-d is, in essence, put into a single shell script, which usually resides somewhere under `/var/spool`, and I think that `at` has some protection against these files being modified after being submitted, though I do not recall the details. (I guess that could be tried out experimentally if you have root access on your machine -- find the file containing your commands and comment out the one you don't want to execute.)

Comment: can you please give me reference from where did you get this information?

Comment: I looked at the source code of `at` and `atd` at some point -- it's fairly short and fairly well-commented (if you ignore things like the time parsing code).

Comment: [Here's the source online](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/at/3.1.11/files.html), and I must apologize -- actually there seems not to be any protection of the scheduled jobs apart form the fact that permissions on `/var/spool/atjobs` are fairly restrictive.